# Vue data fetched object not available in setup()

Tags: vue.js

I am rendering a jspreadsheet component with data fetched from fastapi.

```
<template>
  <h1>Synthèse évaluation fournisseur</h1>
  <VueJSpreadsheet v-model="data.table" :options="myOption" />
  {{ data.columns }}
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, onMounted, isProxy, toRaw, ref } from "vue";
import VueJSpreadsheet from "vue3_jspreadsheet";
import "vue3_jspreadsheet/dist/vue3_jspreadsheet.css";

export default {
  components: {
    VueJSpreadsheet,
  },
  setup() {
    // var intervalID = setInterval(init, 3000);

    var data = reactive({
      table: [],
      columns: [],
    });


    async function load_data() {
      const response = await fetch("http://LOCALHOST:8080/supplier_overview");
      return await response.json();
    }

    load_data().then((response)=>{
      data.table=JSON.parse(response.result.data)
      data.columns=(response.result.columns)
    });

    console.log(data.columns)

    const myOption = ref({
      columns: data.columns,
      search: true,
      filters: true,
      includeHeadersOnDownload: true,
      includeHeadersOnCopy: true,
      defaultColAlign: "left",
      tableOverflow: true,
      tableHeight: "800px",
      parseFormulas: true,
      copyCompatibility: true,
    });

    return {
      data,
      myOption,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

whereas data.columns is rendered correctly in the template, I cannot pass it to myOptions .
The proxy is empty with `console.log(data.columns)` whereas {{data.columns}} returns the correct array :

```
[ { "title": "period" }, { "title": "fournisseur" }, { "title": "Qualité" }, { "title": "Rques Qualité" }, { "title": "Logistique" }, { "title": "Rques Logistique" }, { "title": "Cout" }, { "title": "Rques Cout" }, { "title": "Système" }, { "title": "Rques Système" }, { "title": "Mot QLCS" }, { "title": "Note" }, { "title": "Rques" } ]
```

Any ideas why I cannot passed it correctly to myOptions ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with the variable **myOptions**

```js
setup() {
  async function load_data() {
     const response = await fetch("http://LOCALHOST:8080/supplier_overview");
     return await response.json();
  }
  //the function is async, 1 will be called after 2, so the result is empty
  load_data().then((response)=>{
     data.table=JSON.parse(response.result.data)
     //1
     data.columns=(response.result.columns)
  });
  //2
  console.log(data.columns)

}
```

Comment: Undertsood, but then how can I force data.columns to be evaluated before declaring myOptions ?

Comment: myOptions is a reactive object, when the data.columns changed, the myOptions.columns will change too